# Submit button inside a while loop doesnt work

Tags: php

I need a help to make the submit button inside the while loop work. I design a code that fetch the value from DB and user has to approve or reject the pulled value. So when user click OK, then the DB should be updated with a OK value. I dont know where is the problem is that my OK button doesnt work,

When user click OK, then it should go to approval.php page

```
     <?php
            if ($_POST['action'] == 'show'){

                $requestCompSql = "SELECT REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.PROJECT_NAME, 
                                          REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE, 
                                          REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.THICKNESS, 
                                          REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.QTY_REQUESTED,                                           
                                          REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.REQUESTER, 
                                          REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.REQUEST_DATE 
                                                FROM REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING 
                                                WHERE REQUEST_COMPONENT_CUTTING.BASE_PLATE = '{$_POST["bp"]}'";

                $requestCompParse = oci_parse($conn, $requestCompSql);

                oci_execute($requestCompParse);

                while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($requestCompParse)){

                echo "<form action='approval.php'>";
                echo "<div class='table-responsive'>";
                echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
                                        echo '<table cellspacing = "0"';
                                            echo '<thead>';
                                            echo '<tr>
                                                      <th>PROJECT</th>
                                                      <th>BASEPLATE</th>
                                                      <th>THICKNESS</th>
                                                      <th>QTY REQUESTED</th>
                                                      <th>REQUESTER</th>   
                                                      <th>REQ. DATE</th>
                                                      <th align="center">ACTION</th>  
                                                  </tr>
                                                  </thead>';

                                             echo "<tbody>";
                                                echo "<tr class='warning'><td>$row[PROJECT_NAME]</td>";
                                                echo "<td>$row[BASE_PLATE]</td>";
                                                echo "<td>$row[THICKNESS]</td>";
                                                echo "<td>$row[QTY_REQUESTED]</td>";
                                                echo "<td>$row[REQUESTER]</td>";
                                                echo "<td>$row[REQUEST_DATE]</td>";
                                                echo "<td><input type='button' value='OK' class='btn btn-success'>
                                                    <input type='button' value='REJECT' class='btn btn-danger'></td>";

                                                echo "</tr>";
                                             echo "</tbody>";
                                         echo "<table cellspacing = '0'";
                                         echo "</form>";
                                         echo "</div>";
                }

            }

            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a submit button you need to use

```
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
```

You used

```
    <input type="button" value="OK">
```

which can be used for javascript execution. Same for the reject button. You could however send the form with javascript (which is not recommended, as some choose to turn of javascript) by using something like this:

```
    <input type="button" value="OK" onClick="document.forms[0].submit()">
```

Answer (score 2):

The button needs to be of type="submit" and not only of type="button"

```
echo "<td><input type='submit' value='OK' class='btn btn-success'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems in your code. Firstly if you are posting data through form, then there should be `method` property for the form like:

```
 echo "<form action='approval.php' method='post'>";
```

Secondly, if you are submitting the form on clicking the button, then the type of button should be `submit` instead of `button`.

```
<input type='submit' value='OK' class='btn btn-success'>
```

Comment: can i have 2 buttons with both type='submit'? because each button should perform different action in approval.php

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `type='button'` you should add Javascript to submit the form such as `onclick='submit();'`